# Autotest equivalent for PHP?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have been using [autotest](http://www.zenspider.com/ZSS/Products/ZenTest/) for unit testing in ruby. Is there an equivalent for PHP that will run my unit tests after my code has been updated? I am using PHPUnit and Eclipse.

Comment: You're looking for php continuous integration tools? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+continuous-integration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144274/alternative-to-phpundercontrol-is-it-the-best Common answers appear to be: phpundercontrol phing and xinc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use watchr to watch your directory and run phpunit whenever a file changes.

http://github.com/mynyml/watchr

Comment: Here's a quick script I wrote, you can customize it to your own directory structure: http://gist.github.com/287950

Answer (score 3):

[hot phpunit runner](https://github.com/slavahatnuke/hot-phpunit-runner)

that is watcher for files and entities

can run tests for changed entities/domains and tests too

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution that is implemented in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I use grunt and grunt-phpunit to watch my application and run the tests when I change the files.

http://michaelcalkins.com/post/71024731696/run-phpunit-tests-continuously-using-grunt

Answer (score 0):

I use the [`entr` command](http://entrproject.org/) for this kind of task. It receives a list of files and runs the given command when one of the file changes.

Example:

```
find src test -name "*.php" -type f | entr phpunit
```

The good thing about `entr` is that it's language- and command-agnostic, I can use it for phpunit, JavaScript unit test, linting, etc. Also, compared to `watchr`, I only have to install one command instead of a ruby runtime.